# Google sheet ImportXML returns Imported Content is Empty

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to parse data from this [website](https://track.aftership.com/cnexps/LL443994747LU?referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aftership.com%2Ffr%2Fcouriers%2Fcnexps) through `IMPORTXML` from a google spreadsheet.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://track.aftership.com/cnexps/LL443994747LU?referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aftership.com%2Ffr%2Fcouriers%2Fcnexps","//*[@id='__next']/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/section[2]/p")
```

The objective is to get the value "In transit"

Reading other posts with similar issues, I'm afraid that the content cannot be parsed. Could you confirm? Could you suggest a workaround?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 1):

Content can't be parsed directly since dynamic rendering is used. Selenium or other specific tools are required. A possible workaround :

Since "track.aftership.com" has multiple layers of protection to fetch directly the data, we could use another service. "packages24.com" seems a good candidate. Content can't also be parsed directly but we can manage the problem this time.

[image: Transit]

In B2, you have the link of the request (add your tracking number after the "=")

```
https://www.packages24.com/track?number=LL443994747LU
```

In B3, IMPORTXML+substring functions to extract the url containing the authorization to consult the API.

```
=IMPORTXML(B2;"substring-after(substring-before(//script[contains(.,'api.packages24')],""',""),'url: ')")
```

In B5, ImportJSON function (to import the JSON according the url found in B3) + QUERY to select only the column "Status" and the last record.

```
=QUERY(ImportJSON(B3);"SELECT Col3 limit 1";1)
```

The script to import JSON data in GoogleSheets is available below (credits to Paul Gambill) : https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164

In B6 you have the result.